# Definition queries deleting themselves in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, definition-query

After switching to ArcMap 10.2 I've noticed that my definiton queries will seemingly randomly remove themselves. I have no idea what triggers the deletion since I have noticed it after reordering items in the TOC, turning layers on or off, adding new layers, changing the symbology, even after Applying a DQ and having it show up then hitting OK only to have it not work.

I have tested the issue with a variety of MXDs, different project files, GDBs, SHPS, different company servers, etc. The issue arises for all of them. Recently, we completely removed all things Arc and are currently reinstalling things one at a time. We thought maybe it was one of the third party extensions that I use and have narrowed it down to either the DWR addons for IWFM tools or AquaVeo's ArcHydro extension. Things were going fine for a couple weeks after adding ArcHydro, and we thought the issue was maybe a caching or temporary file thing until yesterday when the problem popped up again.

I was just curious if anyone else has run into this issue, what things were tried on your end, and if you managed to fix it without having to call ESRI (I am NOT looking forward to calling ESRI, but that's the next step in this process since we cannot pinpoint it to a specific third party extension).

Comment: If you do end up calling ESRI, please report back, I've never had this problem and it sounds potentially serious.

Comment: Definition queries are one part of ArcGIS for Desktop that I have never had cause to doubt. I would look for anything that causes layers to be removed/added or maps to be overwritten. In both cases a layer without a definition query could be taking the place of another you set one for.  Also, look for any ArcPy or ArcObjects code that may be removing definition queries by setting them to ""

Comment: Any of these layers created from Layer Selections?

Comment: @Jakub , None of the layers are created from Layer Selections.

Comment: Are you using Data Driven Pages? There was an old bug in DS Mapbook which is the ancestor for Data Driven Pages which erased definition queries that weren't set up using the expected characters... The Data Driven Pages program modifies definition queries looking for specific sequences of characters. I know it's unlikely but still possible. Another possibility is if the field used in the query is hidden in the fields tab - this may fail validation (as the field is invisible) and be removed. If your field (or alias) is a reserved word this may also cause validation to fail.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson , None of the MXDs I have been working in recently have Data Driven Pages. Curious thing, however, I just noticed that the Data Driven Pages Toolbar is missing from my toolbar area. I know that I added it, because I do have a need to build a Mapbook in the near future. I have no hidden fields in any of the files that I have tried, and, so far as I know, none of the fields contain reserved words. I will look into Data Driven Pages as a possibility, even though it is not turned on. Thanks!

Comment: Even if it's not turned on it can still respond to events, usually if a tool is turned off it simply returns immediately. If you are having difficulty with your data driven pages toolbar then it's starting to look like the culprit - the bad news is that broken interfaces can be stubborn and even if uninstalled completely break immediately on re-installation as the issue is possibly in the registry; on occasions I've had to go back to installing windows again to fix a stubborn interface that left crud in the registry but that wasn't an Esri interface.